# Index out of bounds when using a two-dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am creating a text based minesweeper game in Java. The game works fine if a user creates a perfect square for a game board, however if they enter two different values, I get an exception at the point where I add the mines into the 2d array:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 19
    at Grid.addMines(Grid.java:77)
```

Add mines (Line 77 is if statement):

```
public void addMines()
    {
        Random generator = new Random();
        int count = 0;

        while (count < numMines)
        {
            int x = generator.nextInt(rows);
            int y = generator.nextInt(columns);

            if (grid[x][y].minePresent == false)
            {
                grid[x][y].setCurrent("*");
                grid[x][y].minePresent = true;
                count++;
            }
            else
                continue;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in the access of your game *fields*:

```
if (grid[x][y].minePresent == false)
        {
            grid[x][y].setCurrent("*");
            grid[x][y].minePresent = true;
            count++;
        }
```

Here you should access them in a reverse order:

```
grid[y][x].setCurrent("*"); // and so on
```

because of the way you created the 2d-array.

Comment: This turned out to be correct, As when I created the 2d array, I had defined columns in the first for loop, where in other places it was defined secondly. Thanks

Comment: Exactly. Glad I could help. Cheers!

Comment: @Mrambo: You really need to work out consistent terminology then. It's fine to decide either to put the row number first or the column number first when accessing the array, but understand what you're doing. Perhaps it would be clearer if instead of `x` and `y` you used `column` and `row`. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 6):

This looks suspicious to me:

```
int x = generator.nextInt(rows);
int y = generator.nextInt(columns);
```

Given that an `x` value specifies a column usually, I suspect you want:

```
int x = generator.nextInt(columns);
int y = generator.nextInt(rows);
```

Or to be clearer still:

```
int column = generator.nextInt(columns);
int row = generator.nextInt(rows);
```

Then *consistently* either use:

```
Foo[][] grid = new Foo[rows][columns];
...
grid[row][column] = ...;
```

or:

```
Foo[][] grid = new Foo[columns][rows];
...
grid[column][row] = ...;
```

Either of those is fine, but you'd got the wrong order because you'd changed from a "column/row" model to an "x/y" model inconsistently.

It's worth taking a step back to work out how to diagnose similar problems in the future. If something works when two values are the same (rows and columns in this case) and fails when they're different, then *usually* that means you're using one of the values instead of the other somewhere. So trace your code carefully back from the error spot, working out anywhere where those values are used, and checking them.

Comment: I agree with your second paragraph and will do so, However I am sure X represents rows typically and Y columns.

Comment: @Mrambo: No, it really doesn't. The X value varies horizontally - just as a column value does. The Y value varies vertically, just as a row value does. If a table or grid has 5 rows, then the Y value for any cell would be in the range 0-4 or 1-5 typically. If it has 20 columns, then the X value for any cell would be in the range 0-19 or 1-20.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that grid has dimensions smaller than [rows][columns]?

You can check that by doing something like that:

```
System.out.println(grid.length+"/"+rows);
System.out.println(grid[0].length+"/"+columns);
```

If any of the left values are smaller than the right values then you've got your culprit. Have a look at the initialization of grid if you accidentally provided smaller numbers.

Answer (score -2):

Given the answer from Jon above also, according to doc http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28%29

> All 2^32 possible int values are produced with (approximately) equal probability.

E.g. negatives would be returned as well. You must use Math.abs and do int x = Math.abs(generator.nextInt(columns));

Comment: He's using `nextInt(int n)`, which returns a value in the range [0, x).

Comment: Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive)

Comment: No need nextInt(int n) generates between 0(inclusive) and n exclusive as per java docs. Kindly modify above E.g. statement for negatives.